# ARIMA unusual forcasts

Tags: time-series

I am trying to implement the ARIMA model using statsmodels. I get really unusual results for my predictions, and was hoping for advice on fixing this.

```
arima = tsa.ARIMA(train[endogenous], exog=train.drop(endogenous,axis=1), order=(2,2,0),freq='B')
results = arima.fit()
prediction = results.predict(start=1,end=len(x)-1,exog=x.drop(endogenous,axis=1))
```

My actual dataset is this

```
2012-01-05    659.010
2012-01-06    650.020
2012-01-09    622.940
...
2013-11-08    1016.03
2013-11-11    1010.59
2013-11-12    1011.78
2013-11-13    1032.47
```

Prediction gives me this

```
2012-01-05   -10.551134
2012-01-06    -8.937889
2012-01-09   -27.941221
...
2013-11-08    14.739148
2013-11-11    22.567270
2013-11-12     1.844993
2013-11-13   -42.794671
```

It's unusual how even on examples that I trained on, the predictions aren't even in the same ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for an ARIMA(2,2,0) model.  So, your model fit will be done on twice-differenced data.  I believe the predicted values are predictions of the twice-differenced data, not the original data.